# Is there a way to take an object with a mirror side and make it one whole object?

Tags: animation, retopology, mirror-modifier

So I have this model that I retopologized, and it has the mirror modifier applied to it. The entire left side is mirrored. I want to rig this model for animation, and I just wanted to know if this mirror modifier is going to interfere with the posing this figure. If it is, then how do I solve this problem? I would imagine there's a tool that makes it a whole mesh, but I just need some clarification. If no such tool exists, and the mirror modifier is going to be a problem, then what should I do? I'm using 2.93, by the way. I only say that because the mirror modifier seems to work differently with each version.[image]

Comment: On default settings, a mirror modifier *does* make a whole mesh (via "merge" option.)  Applying a modifier has a special meaning in Blender and I think you're probably not using that meaning (see the modifier dropdown, see what happens when you "apply" the mirror modifier.)  It is possible to use an armature modifier with a live mirror modifier; the mirror mod needs to have vertex groups enabled, bones need to be named appropriately (.L, .R), and the mirror needs to be before the armature.  Answering as a comment because this is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you're done mirroring you can apply the mirror modifier and the mirrored side will become "real"

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks!